# How to let gnome screensaver to switch to another user on inactivity timeout?

Tags: scripting, gnome, screensaver

Instead of a screensaver, I wish to switch to another user on activity timeout.

Under "switch to another user", I understand switching to his/her session, if he/she is already logged in.

Is it somehow possible, maybe by some scripting?

Comment: could you explain what you mean with "switch to another user"? You mean to another session of another user that's already logged in?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, exactly! I clarified.